# Ruby: implementing function returning an Enumerator

Tags: ruby, hash, ienumerator

For a personal `Hash` implementation, I would like to create a banged version of `map`,  `map!`, ie, a version that changes the current object, like the one that exists for `Array`. When a block is given, the implementation below seems to work correctly:

```
class MyHash < Hash

  def map! &block
    self.map { |ek, ev| self[ek] = block[ev] }  if block_given?
    # how to return the Enumerator if block not given?
  end

end
```

When called without a block, the `hash.map` returns an `Enumerator`, like in the example below:

```
h.map
=> #<Enumerator: {1=>2, 12=>21, 6=>3}:map>
```

What should I add to my function to make it return the Enumerator when a block is not given?

Answer (score 2):

This is surprisingly easy using [`Object#to_enum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-to_enum)

```
class MyHash < Hash
  def map!
    if block_given?
      each { |k, v| self[k] = yield v }
    else
      to_enum :map!
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you give an example of this? How is it used when a block is not given?

Comment: An example: `a = [1,2,3]; a.map!.with_index { |n,i| [2*n,i] }; a #=> [[2, 0], [4, 1], [6, 2]]`.

Comment: It might be clearer to write the above example as follows. a = [1,2,3]; enum = a.map! #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:map!>; enum.with_index { |n,i| [2*n,i] } #=> [[2, 0], [4, 1], [6, 2]]; a #=> [[2, 0], [4, 1], [6, 2]]`.

Comment: This could also be written `def map! &block`, with the operative line replaced  with `each { |k, v| self[k] = block.call(v) }` (or even left as is).

Answer (score -1):

I can't get what your code does, but you can try to return `self.each`:

```
def map! &block
    if block_given?
        self.map { |ek, ev| self[ek] = block[ev] }
    else
        self.each
    end
end
```

Comment: This relies on the method caller performing the assignment themselves. I think OP wants the block to simply return a new value for each key.